# Python: __add__ and +, different behavior with float and integer

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, addition

When adding an integer value to a float value, I realized that `__add__` method is working fine if called on float, such as this:

```
>>> n = 2.0
>>> m = 1
>>> n.__add__(m)
3.0
```

but not if called on an integer:

```
>>> m.__add__(n)
NotImplemented
```

At first I thought that `__add__` was just being implemented differently for `int` and `float` types (like float types accepting to be added to int types, but not the opposite). Then I noticed that everything works fine if I use the + operator instead:

```
>>> n + m
3.0
>>> m + n
3.0
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Are `__add__` and `+` not deeply related to each other?

Comment: `NotImplemented` also returned for `m.__radd__(n)`

Comment: @this-vidor: Wrong `__radd__` method there.

Comment: @user2357112 True! Then that's the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a + b` does not directly translate to `a.__add__(b)`. It also tries `b.__radd__(a)` if `a.__add__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`, or if `b` is an instance of a subtype of `a`'s type.

Comment: I'm still confused. How does this explain the behavior of *anInt.__add__(aFloat)* == *NotImplemented* but *aFloat.__add__(anInt)* produces a float sum? I would think + / `__add__` would both be commutative?

Comment: @RBV: Neither `+` nor `__add__` are commutative. `+` isn't commutative because of cases like `[1] + [2] != [2] + [1]`, and `__add__` isn't commutative even for cases when `+` is commutative because only one argument needs to know how to handle the operation.